# Django - querying 2 tables with a many to many mapping table

Tags: django, postgresql

If i have two tables `people` and `fruits` with a third table that maps a many to many relationship between the two.

*PEOPLE TABLE*

```
id    person
1     bob
2     alice
```

*FRUITS TABLE*

```
id    fruit
1     apple
2     pear
3     orange
4     grapes
```

*PEOPLE_FRUITS_MAP*

```
id    person_id    fruit_id
1     1            1
2     1            3
3     1            4
4     2            1
```

How would I get a **Django** QuerySet containing the names of all the fruits related to bob for example.

I guess in SQL it would be something like:

```
SELECT
   fruits.id AS fid,
   fruits.name AS fn,
FROM
   people 
   LEFT JOIN
      people_fruits_map 
      ON people.id = people_fruits_map.person_id 
   LEFT JOIN
      fruits 
      ON fruits.id = people_fruits_map.fruit_id 
WHERE
   person.id = 1;
```

result of query

```
fid    fn
--------------
1      apple
3      orange
4      grapes
```

*DJANGO MODELS*

```
class Fruits(models.Model):
    fruit = models.TextField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'fruits'


class People(models.Model):
    person = models.TextField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'people'


class PeopleFruitsMap(models.Model):
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruits, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    people = models.ForeignKey(People, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
 
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'people_fruits_map'
```

Comment: By Django object, I assume you mean Django queryset object? If yes, please add the code for the models for these tables as that will be required for answering your question

Comment: @Mehak that is what I should write. I am new to all this so don't know the correct terminology

Comment: That's okay. Please add the code for models as well.

Comment: @Mehak models added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For querying a many to many relation from your given models, you can write an ORM query in Django.

First you can add a reverse relation name in your model to make it more readable. This is not a necessary step as Django adds a default name itself if you don't.

In your `PeopleFruitsMap` model, add related_name

```
class PeopleFruitsMap(models.Model):
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruits, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='fruit_to_people_mapping')
    people = models.ForeignKey(People, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'people_fruits_map'
```

Now try running this query in your Django shell. Run `python manage.py shell`, then run this query, where 1 is the id you require:

```
from your_app.models import Fruit
fruits = Fruit.objects.filter(fruit_to_people_mapping__people__id=1)
```

Id can be passed dynamically if you want.
To match the query, you can always use `print(fruits.query)` to check the equivalent postgres query.

Related name helps you refer the reverse relations in model objects, in your case, it will check the `PeopleFruitsMap` model mapping and in that mapping, we can query the people relation for matching the id.

References:
[Django Querying Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/)